# Rebuild a widgets in searchdelegate flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to rebuild the buildSuggestions method that returns a widget that the defined below
and resultInfo getting the result from TMDB API search that a string as an input
how can i recall the resultInfo and rebuild it.

```
  @override
 Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    if (query.length > 1) {
      return ResultInfo(s: query);
    }
    return ResultInfo(s: "old");
    //ResultInfo not updating after the query updates 
  }
```

[this](https://github.com/shobhit3661/Movie-Munch/blob/master/movie_munch/lib/screens/home_screen.dart) is the home screen code where searchdelegate is defined and [here](https://github.com/shobhit3661/Movie-Munch/blob/master/movie_munch/lib/widgets/result.dart) you can find the code for ResultInfo widget.

Comment: Please provide some code to help us understand  better

Comment: I have passed the link to my git repo and code you can check the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: After looking at the project, you need to call the `getMovies` function from the `buildSuggestions` build method because `initState` was only getting called once despite the rebuilds. Add this and you're good.

```
 @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    if (query != '') {
      searchResult.getMovies(query); // do the search from here
      return ResultInfo(searchString: query);
    }
    return ResultInfo(searchString: "old");
  }
}
```

You can leave the search in `initState` also so you don't get a blank list when you navigate to the search page.

OLD ANSWER:

Any time the `query` changes in a widget that extends `SearchDelegate`, `buildSuggestions` is called. You can verify that by adding a print statement in the `buildSuggestions` build method.

I see a couple issues here:

```
class ResultInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  final String s;
  ResultInfo({Key key, @required this.s}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MovieInfoState createState() => _MovieInfoState(s);
}

class _MovieInfoState extends State<ResultInfo> {
  // final String s;  don't need this here
  _MovieInfoState(this.s);
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    searchResult.getMovies(widget.s); // access the actual parameter you passed in with widget.s 
  }
```

When you pass a value into a stateful widget you don't re-declare the same value again in the stateful part, you access what was passed in with `widget.variable`. So in your case you were passing in a null value into the `getMovies` function.

So assuming your stream functionality is all working, that simple change alone should fix your issue.

And in the interest of your code being readable by other people, I suggest a better variable name than `s`, like `query` for example because that's what it is. Anyone reading your code has no idea what `s` is and what it's for until they dig around a bit.

Second issue:

```
if (query.length > 1) { // won't return results until 2nd character is input
      return ResultInfo(s: query);
    }
    return ResultInfo(s: "old");
  }
```

Maybe its your intention to only return `ResultInfo(s: query)` until more than one character is input, but if its not, change your condition to this

```
if (query != '') {
      return ResultInfo(s: query);
    }
    return ResultInfo(s: "old");
  }
```

Comment: I have updated the code but still not working the ResultInfo widget still not rebuild after query updates.

Comment: Your updates look good, I would debug your `StreamBuilder` and your `getMovies` function then. As a test, you could bypass the `StreamBuilder` and just return a `Text(widget.searchString)`. You should see it update as you type. I don't see the origin of the `getMovies` function so I can't verify your stream on my end.

Comment: can you tell me how can I setState in 'ResultInfo' if string searchString changes. that will resolve the issue i think and you can access my whole repo of flutter project in links

Comment: You don't need set state because everything inside the 'buildSuggestions' gets rebuilt every time the query string changes. I'll have a look at your full project later today.

Comment: that will be really helpful

Comment: No problem. Your app has a nice UI by the way but FYI I was getting some overflow errors on the LG G7 ThinQ that I use for developing. I suggest setting up an emulator with a smaller screen to have a look at that if you don't have a smaller phone to test with.

Comment: yes I will look definitely have a look at that